# Camera opens but shows no image

Tags: windows-7, webcam, camera

I have an built-in camera in my laptop (System-Windows 7, 64-bit). It used to work fine usually in zoom. But now when I turn on my camera in zoom it displays the white light besides the camera showing that the camera is switched on but I can not see myself. Also previously when I used to turn off my camera the white light used to vanish but now even after switching off the camera the white light doesn't goes.

I tried to go to device manager and scan the Camera under Imaging Devices for hardware changes and updated it but still cam doesn't show an image. I tried to uninstalled the device then scan for hardware changes and it did get installed back but still no image.

When I tried to run my camera on webcammictest.com it shows

> A hardware error has occurred

> Although you granted permission to use the appropriate devices, there was a hardware error at the operating system, browser, or web page level that prevented access to the device.

> Try unplugging the device from the computer and plugging it back in.

Can anyone please help me what to do?

Comment: Please start by uninstalling and reinstalling the drivers

Comment: @mashuptwice I had already uninstalled my camera drive this one https://i.stack.imgur.com/B56MC.png and restarted my computer and the camera drive came by itself. So it is fine?

Comment: Obviously your camera is not working, so something is not fine. You might want to install the manufacturers driver instead of the one windows provided automatically

Comment: @mashuptwice I tried installing another webcam ArcSoft Webcam Sharing Manager from HP website but again the camera would not open and only black screen would come in zoom and same message come in webcammictest.com. What to do?

Comment: @JitendraSingh, You seem to have installed some kind of software, He/she was talking about *manufacturer's driver*

Comment: What is your computer model ?

Comment: @1NN It is windows 7 64-bit

Comment: I had cams that showed the same behaviour (indication light turned on, but the video stream just showed a black picture) and it turned out to be a faulty cam. Did you get the cam to work with different software or on a different system?

Comment: @Albin it is an inbuilt camera of laptop so it can't be removed and put in other device

Comment: @JitendraSingh not on a different HW device, did you try a different system like Linux, Windows 10 etc.? Did you try other software then Zoom?

Comment: @Albin Yes I tried different softwares like in Zoom, Chrome and Edge but it didn't worked

Comment: @JitendraSingh what about running a different OS on the laptop (see my answer). And does your cam have a build in microphone, try that separately (e.g. via the sound recorder in windows), what happens?

Comment: @Albin, *inbuilt webcams having built in microphone*?

Comment: @SaaranshGarg ah, you are right, that doesn't make sense, thank you for the correction...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a possibility it is a hardware defect, at least in my experience those symptoms were connected with a faulty webcam in the past (control light is on, but no picture is being transmitted).

If the driver solution as "[Saaransh Garg](https://superuser.com/a/1707516/1672996)" suggests in his mail does not work, I would try it on a different OS (Linux, Win10, etc.), which, for example, can be run without replacing your current system, e.g. as a life system on a USB stick (as long as you device supports USB bootup).

Answer (score 2):

You need to follow these steps:

1. Uninstall the driver you had.
2. [Go here](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/laptops) and type in your laptop's serial number or model
3. *I assume that you'll reach the page where drivers are listed.* Expand `All Drivers`, look for Webcam driver. Download and install the driver, as instructed.
4. Restart your computer

This will be good enough for most of the problems. However, if this doesn't helps, Install a generic Windows USB video driver:

1. Go to `Device Manager > Imaging Devices`
2. Right click, select properties
3. Do `Update Driver....` > `Browse the computer` > `Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer.`
4. Deselect `Show compatibe hardware`
5. Select `Microsoft` in left selection, and `USB Video Device` in the right selection
6. Click `Next` to install
7. Restart your computer, check again

If none of this works, I'd say damaged hardware is most likely the cause of your problem.

Comment: Alas but none of the step worked. Can you tell what to do?

Comment: Hmm. Can you tell me what happens when you open the camera app provided by microsoft?

Comment: It just keeps on loading and a white light occurs near inbuilt camera

Comment: Hmm. If I were to Guess, @JitendraSingh, I'd say your Camera is malfunctioning.

Answer (score -1):

I would ask you to try to uninstall the zoom program and reinstall it. If it works on another site or program but not on zoom and it could be an issue with the program itself.

However if your computer detects it but fails to use it in the browser I would pop off the screen frame and detach and reattach the camera physically..

On your keyboard there is a camera button usually F8 I think, you may have simply just disabled your camera by accidentally hitting that button.

I know you trying to reinstalling the drivers but maybe just try rolling them back maybe an update has them acting weird..

And second to last but not least make sure the privacy settings in your computer aren't set to block your camera on certain programs.

If none of the above work I would recommend getting a new camera sorry.

Comment: if the camera is disabled by a keypress or a setting otherwise, then it'd show an error and would not turn the camera on, which isn't the case with the OP here. His camera turns on and shows a total white screen, but nothing else.